# Replace Numerics in Pandas Series with Boolean

Tags: python, pandas, series

Here is a toy series for illustrative purposes.

```
test = pd.Series([True, False, 2.2, 6.6, 0, True])
```

I have a Pandas series that contains True, False, and a bunch of different numeric values. I want to replace all numerics with False so that the entire column is Boolean. How do I accomplish this?
I want it to end up like:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest solution is compare by `True`:

```
test = test == True
print (test)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

For compare floats and integers:

```
test = test.apply(lambda x: False if type(x) in (float, int) else x)
print (test)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Solution with `isinstance`:

```
def testing(x):
    if isinstance(x, bool):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x, (float, int)):
        return False
    else:
        return x

test = test.apply(testing)
print (test)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: test == True :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> test[test!= True] = False
>>> test
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: object
```

Comment: I thought of this, but I assumed it wouldn't work, because I thought any non-zero number was interpreted to be True.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for floats. I can repeat for ints. I'm sure there's a better way though.

```
df.col_1.apply(lambda x: False if type(x)==float else x)
```